# Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float' when normalizing against negative controls in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, statistics

The `neg_ctl_df` dataframe contains negative control and the `coding_gene_df` contains my gene-of-interest.

I want to perform normalization for each sample by subtracting the median of the negative controls within the sample.

Both `samples` and `neg_ctl_median` are `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Negative normalization: Subtract the median of the negative controls within the patient sample
neg_ctl_median = neg_ctl_df.iloc[:,-29:].median()

for gene, samples in coding_gene_df.iloc[:,-29:].iterrows():
  norm_val = samples - neg_ctl_median
  print(norm_val)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    165     try:
--> 166         result = func(left, right)
    167     except TypeError:

9 frames
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
    110         # See GH#5284, GH#5035, GH#19448 for historical reference
    111         if mask.any():
--> 112             result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
    113 
    114     else:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Samples:

`coding_gene_df.iloc[1:10,-29:-27].to_dict()`

```
{'12h_P1_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': {'CNTN2': '6.35',
  'KCNA2': '5.29',
  'LOC79160': '5.99',
  'PTGIS': '5.66',
  'TTTY11': '3.91',
  'VPS4B': '9.68',
  'XRCC1': '9.09',
  'ZC3HC1': '7.19',
  'ZFAS1': '8.68'},
 '48h_P1_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': {'CNTN2': '6.6',
  'KCNA2': '5.36',
  'LOC79160': '6.18',
  'PTGIS': '5.54',
  'TTTY11': '3.92',
  'VPS4B': '9.51',
  'XRCC1': '9.15',
  'ZC3HC1': '7.05',
  'ZFAS1': '8.46'}}
```

Negative controls:

`neg_ctl_df.iloc[1:10,-29:-27].to_dict()`

```
{'12h_P1_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor': {'---': '8.45'},
 '48h_P1_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor': {'---': '8.16'}}
```

Data types:

```
print(type(neg_ctl_median))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(samples))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: `coding_gene_df.iloc[1:10,-29:-27]` values are string?

Comment: @zousan its pandas series

Comment: Yes, but you convert it to dictionary and it shows the values are string, can you do `coding_gene_df.info()` to see what the column -29 dtype is?

Comment: @zousan The dtype of column -29 is `object`

Comment: @melolilili you must write ptint(type(samples.loc[0]))

Comment: Then it is the problem, you should convert it to float as you want to do some number calculations along it. `coding_gene_df.iloc[:,-29]= coding_gene_df.iloc[:,-29].astype(float)` will do it

Answer (score 0):

in your series that has sample value, the values are string type such as '5.29' , '8.46' , etc. python can not operate "-" between string and floats. you must first convert your sample to floats format. you can use from "to_numeric" method in pandas for this

use this code (suppose your 29th col name is sample)

add a line before your for clause

```py
coding_gene_df['sample'] = pd.to_numeric(coding_gene_df['sample'])
for gene, samples in coding_gene_df.iloc[:,-29:].iterrows():
  norm_val = samples - neg_ctl_median
  print(norm_val)
```

also you can remove for clause and use from a faster way such as below:

```py
coding_gene_df['norm_val'] = df.sample - coding_gene_df
```

Comment: Can you please provide code? I tried `to_numeric()` but got an error `'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'`

Comment: @melolilili send your code for me to modify it